# Class does not support Automation error at Ready State in web scraping

Tags: excel, vba

Below code fills data on the web page, clicks a button and at the end saves web page code to a local file. Unfortunately, it works on only my machine. At others, it displays below error at 1st `Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4`. Using Office 365 ProPlus on both machines. Please help me in this.

[image][image]

```
Sub SaveHTml()
    Dim str, URL As String
    Dim ie, frm As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FF As Integer
    Dim wb As WebBrowser
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

str = Sheets("Main_Page").Range("L1").Value
URL = "https://tiweb.industrysoftware.automation.siemens.com/prdata/cgi-bin/n_prdata_index.cgi" 'for TEST
FileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\Test.htm"

Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate URL

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

ie.Document.getelementsbyname("pr_numbers")(0).Value = 564684
' Application.SendKeys ("{NUMLOCK}~")
' Application.SendKeys "{NUMLOCK}"

Call ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button").Item(1).Click

''Call IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("return check_mvsub(this)", "JavaScript")
Do
Loop While ie.Busy

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile FileName

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
FF = FreeFile
Open FileName For Output As #FF

With ie.Document.body
    Print #FF, .outerHTML & .innerHTML
End With

Close #FF

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you verified all the other folks have the same references available on their machines? I've had people with different versions of the references available.

Comment: Yes. Same as are in snapshot.

Comment: How do I check whether references does exists? Or any other way to do this task?